# Pointing to array of bitsets

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address, bitset

I wonder if the following construction is possible:

```
typedef std::bitset<4> BIT4;
BIT4* x=new BIT4[3];
BIT4* y=new BIT4[5];
```

My concerns are:

(1) is the array of BIT4 a legal construction?

(2) if yes, how the pointer will address these arrays of size 3 and 5? last element of these arrays seems to take 1/2 byte, is another half just lost and we start the next array from a new byte or how does it work?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: (1) yes;
(2) `std::bitset<4>` is not guaranteed whatsoever to occupy only 4-bits of memory.

Comment: @veer so, it could be that each std::bitset<4> in the array takes the whole byte? What does it depend on?

Comment: @gartenzwerg: By definition, nothing takes up less than `sizeof(char)`, which is 1. It itself has `CHAR_BIT` bits, usually 8, and guaranteed to be at least 8. So no data type in the language takes up fewer than 8 bits.

Comment: Note that an object has some overhead. So a `std::bitset<4>` definitely uses more than four bits of memory.

Comment: @Code-Guru AFAIK, classes without virtual members or multiple inheritance should not have any overhead. However, bitsets are promoted to the next largest element, so instance bit size will probably not be the size of the bitset element.

Comment: @NisonMaël Good point. Without virtual functions, there would be no reason for a vtable and all function calls can be determined at compile-time. I hadn't gone that extra step in my thinking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do as I understand is

use 12 bits for 3 elements in an array called x

use 20 bits for 5 elements in an array called y

This is wrong as you will end up using:

- 3 bytes for x
- 5 bytes for y

if you want to achieve what you want you need to do it like this:

```
std::bitset<4*3> x;   // this will occupy 12 + 4 Padding Bits = 2 bytes
std::bitset<4*5> y;   // this will occupy 20 + 4 Padding Bits = 3 bytes
```

and you can of course allocate it dynamically if you want to.